# SSAO artefacts on iPhone (OpenGL ES)

Tags: shader, opengl-es

I've never written shaders before, and now I'm trying to implement SSAO with SceneKit on OS X and iOS. I'm trying different SSAO shaders that I find, e.g. from Three.js, [this one](http://theorangeduck.com/page/pure-depth-ssao), and [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms33WB).

On OS X they all work as they should, but on iPhone *all* of them giving me the same artefacts (images show SSAO pass only). The lines move when I move the camera. So it must be because of some differences of OpenGL ES. Anyone knows what's wrong?

[image: img1] [image: img2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved by adding `precision highp sampler2D` to my shaders.

About default precision settings on ES - https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf page 36.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the precision before? Low or Medium?

Comment: I found a document saying it's low for samplers and high for float/int by default on ES. Oh, ints depend on shader type I've added link to my answer.

Comment: OK. Was just wondering if you'd tried mediump as there could be performance (and power) benefits.

Comment: mediump doesn't help in my case, and also I don't notice any significant performance difference either.